# Number of occurences of numbers in a list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of numbers that I would like to know how many times they occur in another list.

```
First list:
1
14
234
34534

Second list:
1
15
234
543455
```

This should produce **2** (1 and 234 appear in the second list).

Any advice? :)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: I like the solution provided by CharlieRB. But I think the data might be too trivial as an example and not fully explained. Perhaps? To the OP: Does the list need to account for any occurrences or repeated data, no matter what line(row) it's on? Important.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e). There are a couple ways to use it, but this seems the simplest.

> =SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4=B1:B4))

In the example I have used your `First list` in column A and `Second list` in column B. The formula was placed in `C1`, where it sums the occurrences where values in A are equal to values in B.

*Note: The double negative (`--`) in the formula changes `TRUE/FALSE` returns to `1/0` so they can be totaled.*

[image]

Comment: I've added a note to the answer. We can delete these comments to reduce clutter.

Comment: Very interesting, Iv'e never seen this before. I tried it out. There seems to be a problem? If it is a problem? This formula `SUMPRODUCT` seems to only count equivalences if they are aligned horizontally only (e.g. if 234 was in B2 rather than B3, then it doesn't count.

Comment: It is not a problem. The formula is comparing the list in column A to the list in column B, not unto itself. Therefore, it will not find duplicates in the same list. This is what the OP asked for when they asked to find out "*how many times they occur in **another** list*".

Comment: I understand. Put another 234 in A2. The (C2) result is still 2. Or, put a 15 in A3, the answer turns to '1'.

Answer (score 0):

**List A**: Search Area. *Static*.

**List B**: Criteria against List A. *Dynamic*; can change.

> I have a list of numbers (List B) that I would like to know how many times they
>   occur in another list (List A).

List B, Cell B2: `=COUNTIF(B2, A:A)` Does '1' exist in List A? 1 times.

List B, Cell B7: `=COUNTIF(B7, A:A)` Does '234' exist in List A? 3 times.

[image]

**Pivot Table**:

Tab:Insert > Pivot Table

Reference A1:C8 -- List1,ListB,CountIF

Table in Sheet: F1

     **Setting-Up the Pivot Table contents**:

          Reveal two pieces of data: 'List B' and 'CountIf'

          Left Side: The rows of List B where occurrences occur in List A.

          Top Row: Count Values (1, 3) >> 1 and 14 '1 time', 234 '3 times'